# unable to add columns to a existing table using C

Tags: sql, c, postgresql

The following program tries to insert a new row and a new column to an already existing database with a table "people" containing four cols (id, lastname, firstname, phonenumber). While the row gets inserted successfully, the column is not getting added.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <libpq-fe.h>
    #include <string.h>

    int main() 
    {
     PGconn *conn;
     PGresult *res;
     int rec_count;
     int row;
     int col;

     conn = PQconnectdb("dbname=test host=localhost user=abc1 password=xyz1");

         if(PQstatus(conn) == CONNECTION_BAD) {
             puts("We were unable to connect to the database");
             exit(0);
         }

     res = PQexec(conn,"INSERT INTO people VALUES (5, 'XXX', 'YYY', '7633839276');");
     if(PQresultStatus(res) != PGRES_COMMAND_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Insertion Failed1: %s", PQerrorMessage(conn));
        PQclear(res);
         }
     else
        printf("Successfully inserted value in Table..... \n");

         res = PQexec(conn,"update people set phonenumber=\'5055559999\' where id=3");
     if(PQresultStatus(res) != PGRES_COMMAND_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Insertion Failed2: %s", PQerrorMessage(conn));
        PQclear(res);
         }

     res = PQexec(conn, "ALTER TABLE people ADD comment VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT 'TRUE'");
     if(PQresultStatus(res) != PGRES_COMMAND_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Insertion Failed3: %s", PQerrorMessage(conn));
        PQclear(res);
         }

  rec_count = PQntuples(res);

      printf("We received %d records.\n", rec_count);
      puts("==========================");

      for(row=0; row<rec_count; row++) {
          for(col=0; col<3; col++) {
              printf("%s\t", PQgetvalue(res, row, col));
           }
           puts("");
        }

      puts("==========================");

      PQclear(res);

      PQfinish(conn);

      return 0;
    }
```

The program after being compiled and linked gives the following output:

```
    $ ./test
    Successfully inserted value in Table..... 
    We received 0 records.
    ==========================
    ==========================
```

In the postgresql environment, the table "people" is updated with an extra row and a column containing "TRUE".

This is my first program with C embedded with postgresql. Please help!!

Comment: edited as suggested by Daniel

Comment: posting the working code which adds the row and col but only in Postgresql environment but not within the program.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
 res = PQexec(conn, "EXEC('UPDATE people SET comment = ''TRUE'';');");
```

should be:

```
 res = PQexec(conn, "UPDATE people SET comment = 'TRUE'");
```

The `EXEC` syntax is part of embedded SQL in C with [ECPG](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ecpg.html). It's not to be combined with `PQexec` from the [C libpq library](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq.html), which is clearly what you're using given the rest of the source code.

Also the result of an UPDATE with no RETURNING clause has `PQresultStatus(res)==PGRES_COMMAND_OK`, not `PGRES_TUPLES_OK`

> PGRES_COMMAND_OK
>
> ```
> Successful completion of a command returning no data.
> ```

See [Command Execution Functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-exec.html)

You also want to test any `PGresult` returned by `PQexec`, not only the result of your last query, because any query may fail.

Comment: Apologies for putting in EXEC, without knowing its exact usage. I had initially done as you suggested as substitute but that didnt work. A google search told me of this EXEC function and I thought of trying my luck with that. But, nothing works still!! The row is always getting added but not the column "comment". I have also changed the line PQresultStatus(res) accordingly.

Comment: @user3258515: see the kind of error checking and display you have for the INSERT, you need to same for the ALTER TABLE statement. And for every call to PQexec in fact.

Comment: Error checking at every PQexec step revealed that the user didnot have permission and hence after correcting that, I could insert the column but only in the postgresql environment. The program however, doesn't gives the output. It gives the following output: Successfully inserted value in Table..... 
We received 0 records.
We did not get any data! which means that rec_count = PQntuples(res); is not working. Can you suggest a possible error here..

Comment: That makes sense. UPDATE does not retrieve any row. The SELECT above should retrieve rows, but your current code does not attempt to read them.

Comment: I just edited the working code. I don't update the table after adding col to it. It works in Postgresql environment but noth within the program. Please provide further suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

How can you retrieve data without doing a SELECT statement ?

Never used PQexec, but i guess the code to add might be like this:

```
 res = PQexec(conn, "ALTER TABLE people ADD comment VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT 'TRUE'");
 if(PQresultStatus(res) != PGRES_COMMAND_OK) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Insertion Failed3: %s", PQerrorMessage(conn));
    PQclear(res);
 }

//Add PQexec and select statement here.
//Something "like" this.
 res = PQexec(conn, "SELECT * FROM people;");
 if(PQresultStatus(res) != PGRES_TUPLES_OK) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Select Failed: %s", PQerrorMessage(conn));
    PQclear(res);
 }

  rec_count = PQntuples(res);

  printf("We received %d records.\n", rec_count);
```

Comment: I wish u replied yesterday... I was struggling and finally got it solved in the exact way as u stated above.. So thanks to both u and Daniel who kept on pushing me.. wish there were options of up-voting at two answers!!